# Loop in twig repeats row 1 of my database 5 times, instead of showing all the rows.

Tags: php, twig, silex

I started to use Silex and Twig early this week. Now I've found a weird problem:

My code in index.php

```
//start sql request. teleport it to the twig file, without satanic php
$app->get('/', function() use ($app){
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM projectvdg'  ;

$text = $app['db']->FetchAssoc($sql);

return $app['twig']->render('start.twig', [
  'content' => $text
]);
});
```

and in 'start.twig' (the file I request in the part above)

```
{% for title in content %}
<p> {{ content.title }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

As far as I understand this, this should be a loop where all (4) titles of my database are shown. But instead it generates this:

**title1**
**title1**
**title1**
**title1**
**title1**

If I try FetchAll, instead of FetchAssoc I get this message:

Twig_Error_Runtime: Key "title" for array with keys "0, 1, 2, 3" does not exist in "start.twig" at line 16

The question is: What mistake did I make in this code? Should I use FetchAll for example, and just change the names of the rows?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're accessing the wrong variable inside the loop.

```
{% for title in content %}
<p> {{ title }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```